# htaccess redirectmatch exclude directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have a htaccess redirect set up on my website (as advised by site hosters) :-

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/$ http://www.somewebsite.com/photos/
ErrorDocument 404 /photos/index.php?/page/404_not_found
```

I'm now looking to migrate to wordpress, but want to be able to build the wordpress site first & get the htacess to ignore a redirect for wordpress.somewebsite.com

I've tried a number of update to the htaccess but don't seem to be able to get the syntax correct

Any help greatfully received

Regards

Comment: I want to exclude wordpress

Comment: /WordPress and subdirectories

Comment: `^/$` matches only landing page, it won't match any sub-directory

Comment: Yes , I understand, so what does the synrltax need to be to exclude the WordPress folder

Comment: `wordpress` folder or any other folder is already excluded from `RedirectMatch permanent ^/$ http://www.somewebsite.com/photos/`

Comment: yes but i don't want it to be, I want to be able to access www.wordpress.somewebsite.com.

Comment: something along the lines of :- redirectmact ^/$ (!wordpress) but that syntax doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your rule to this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /photos/index.php?/page/404_not_found
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !wordpress [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.somewebsite.com/photos/ [L,R=301]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: Thanks that looks to have sorted it !